# The shortest way of using the same event on different Objects

Tags: javascript

I have several  JavaScript Objects (explicit Raphael.js paths), on which I want to apply one event. (e.g.: ".mouseover()")

example:

```
var p = Raphael(1, 1, 600, 600);
        var x = p.path("M100 100 L 300 100") //first raphael.js path
        var y = p.path(("M100 200 L 300 200") //second raphael.js path
        var z = p.path(("M100 300 L 300 300") //third raphael.js path

var doStuff = function () {
                 //doStuff
                };




   x.mouseover(doStuff);
   y.mouseover(doStuff);
   z.mouseover(doStuff);
```

Question: Is there a way to shorten this, 
so that you need to write `.click(doStuff)` only once.

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/utg3k5mo/

Thank You

Comment: What is `onClick`??? What are x,y,z???

Comment: Declare the function once and pass its name to `.onClick`, whatever that is.

Comment: Sorry, of course i meant ".click()"

Comment: x, y, and z are jQuery objects, right?

Comment: I´m not sure anymore, but that is what I think they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have added a jsFiddle, I know what you're talking about. I previously suggested a method that uses jQuery's `.add()` function because you tagged your question with jQuery; however, you are using Raphael and not jQuery, so this method didn't work for you. Please change that tag.

The best way to shorten your procedure is creating an array containing the variables and iterate through it:

```
var array = [x, y, z];
for(var i in array)
    array[i].mouseover(doStuff);
```

---

**Old answer:**

jQuery uses `.click()`. `.onClick()` doesn't exist.

There are two ways to solve your problem:

First, you could store the event handler in a variable and pass it to the `.click()` function:

```
var eventHandler = function() {alert("test");};
x.click(eventHandler);
y.click(eventHandler);
z.click(eventHandler);
```

Or you could add the variables and invoke `.click(function)` on the new set:

```
x.add(y).add(z).click(function() {alert("test");});
```

Comment: Assuming that x, y and z are jQuery objects, this is the best way to go.

Comment: the way with the eventHandler works fine, thank you. The way around ".add" does not work for me.  What I am actually trying to do is to animate a few paths I constructed with Raphael.js. So i got several variables which stores different paths, and i want to add one function on them on the .click() or.mouseover() event. I just wonder if there is a way to shorten: "x.click(eventHandler);
y.click(eventHandler);
z.click(eventHandler);" to a statement that will contain ".click(eventHandler)" only once and will still working on the 3 variables.

Comment: That's weird because the `.add()` method does work for me.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are selecting the variables directly using `$("selector")`, you could just do `$("#x, #y, #z").click(function);`, i.e. use a comma separated list of selectors.

Comment: excuse me for all the misunderstandings, but i am a very beginner to Java Script, and it is very hard for me to make the problem clear. I made an example in JSfiddle, with comments. I really hope that this will help you to understand my intention. http://jsfiddle.net/utg3k5mo/

Comment: I just updated my answer.